# 3TB Hard drive stops reading/locks up after a few minutes of use

Tags: hard-drive, freeze, mbr, gpt

This has been driving me a little batty lately as i dont understand enough to fix the problem. My HTPC (Windows 7Pro 32bit) currently has two USB HDD plugged in under separate ports. The 2TB is a Seagate Goflex Desk (NTFS with MBR) and the 3TB is a Seagate BackupPlus (NTFS with MBR). Currently i have no issue with the 2TB; i can read, stream, copy, write and browse that HDD to my hearts content.

However my 3TB is incredibly unreliable lately. I have Plex running and the 3TB filled w/2TB of media and almost any time i try to stream a file from it, it either locks up immediately or reads data for about a minute and then locks up. After that it may come back anywhere from a few seconds to several minutes, read a small amount of data and then lock up again. I watched using the Resource Monitor and the data read goes completely dead during that time and the Event Viewer isnt reporting any errors. Even browsing the contents using windows explorer usually results in it locking up and holding explorer hostage for a while. So far after Googling i've come up with only two ideas and no solutions:

- A) The hardware is failing as the drive is filling up? (but only 2/3?)
- B) The MBR is causing problems as the drive reaches the theoretical limit?

I've tried the standard things: disk check, defrag, swap cables, swap ports.. nothing helps. I dont want to format the drive and lose all my data, especially if its in vain. But if MBR is the reason the drive is going bonkers then i'll just have to format for GPT (the drive is getting to be pretty useless at this point).

**So to sum up:** Can anyone provide any insight/help on a 3TB USB HDD formatted NTFS under MBR locking up while reading now that the drive is filling up to 2TB of data?

Comment: MBR in a windows 7 system only does the first 2T , doesn't it have to be GPT or partitioned to use more than that? This is where it gets a bit more complex, because these drives have some software, and possible "translation" stuff, which I do not understand completly, and can add a complexity to an issue like this one.

Comment: Sounds like hardware failure.  This has nothing to do with the MBR.  If its failing to read or write data, or taking a long time to do either, then its a hardware problem.

Comment: @Psycogeek: yes, i accidentally had the controllers switched so when i put them with their proper drives it didnt alleviate a thing (which at the same time tested the cables, ports and psu simultaneously). and yes, normally you would need to format it GPT to get at all 3TB, but for some reason my sytem is still letting me add past the 2TB MBR limit. I dont know whats going.

Comment: @Ramhound: I agree that it does sound like the drive is failing. I dont want it too as its not even a year old but It could be that i was using it too much (constant downloading) causing it to wear out faster than designed. But its the way its working that has me wondering if thats the case. The 2TB limit on MBR coupled with the drive finally reaching 2TB of used space feels too coincidental. And the fact that the drive doesnt really fail.. it stalls. It comes back after a while but stalls again quickly. ive had my fair share of failing hard drives in the past and this doesnt act like they did

Comment: Using a hdd won't make it to bad they have 3 hear lifespans for a reason. Mechanical failures are funny.  The 3tb limit is only on booting

Comment: Even if it is a translation by the seagate stuff going on, as long as it is not acting right, myself I would never risk anything and hope.  I have always set mine up myself hopefully avoiding any cheap tricks they would use, and just using it as a controller and a disk. They are some $100-150 a unit here, and I would just get another one, format it and Fill it completly (days and days) and test the data (I use a compare).  I am not having any trouble with the 3T and 4T of mine, I could not even remember all the ways they have been partitioned back from XP even with no GPT at all.

Comment: I do remember taking days to long test them first, be that with the actual (backup) data they would have, or with dummy data. I have no reason to use any of the software that came with it (not a problem just not needed). I just needed reliable backup spaces.